# Is there an analog circuit or filter that can produce constant phase shift over a specific bandwidth?

Tags: analog, filter, phase, phase-shift

I need to match the phase of two signals coming from a pair of transducers over the 10Hz to 4 KHz range, the difference between the two transducers is really close, however one of the transducer lags 7° in phase over the entire band with respect to the other transducer. I need something like an all-pass filter, but instead of it having linear phase shift which varies linearly over frequency, I need a constant phase shift, in my case I need it to be a constant 7° phase shift over the desired bandwidth, I know of no analog network that can perform this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the signal from the transducer broadband, or at any given moment is it approximately sinusoidal?

Comment: It is approximately sinusoidal

Comment: So you want something that delays by (1/f) * (7/360) seconds for f from 10 to 4000?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I thought that maximally flat group delay meant linear phase, not a constant not linearly changing phase.

Comment: @S.s. Brainfa/t. So Is there another way to correct this with PLL tracking>?

Comment: @crj11 a constant delay is linear phase not constant phase, a delay has to shift different phase amounts at different frequencies so the delay remains constant, what I need is not a delay but a constant phase shift regardless of frequency.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist how would you do it with a PLL? like Photon mentioned?

Comment: @S.s. These wouldn’t happen to be Hall Sensor misalignment?

Comment: @S.s  Since it is such a low frequency, the easiest thing to do, as suggested by The Photon is to digitize the signals and delay them the right number of clock cycles and then the convert them back to analog.  As long as you don't have extreme low noise requiements, it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: My window did not see Photon’s answer but yes are these complementary or quadrature?

Comment: Don’t you want a faster ADC or are you averaging?  Differential  quadrature or complimentary, show your timing

Comment: @S.s You only have to do the A/D and D/A on the signal that you want to delay.  Given the delays that you are looking at, the conversion times will just be part of the overall required alignment delay, and shouldn't affect response time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1: Generate the quadrature signal of your input. Sum it with the input in the correct proportions to get 7 degrees phase shift. How to generate a quadrature signal over more than 2 decades of frequency range is left as an exercise for the reader.

Option 2: Make a 1:1 phase locked loop and put an offset in the phase detector to produce 7 degrees phase shift. How to make a good VCO that spans more than 2 decades of frequency range is left as an exercise for the reader.

Option 3: Digitize everything and let software sort it out.

Comment: Option 1 is brilliant!, I cant really see how option 2 works, option 3 is precisely what I want to avoid.

Comment: If the signal amplitude doesn’t matter a PLL IC can lock on with any phase error introduced by a type II mixer offset of Vcc/2 * 7/180 deg  if Vcc/2 is 0 error but getting 3 decades of VCO is better using a log scale voltage-controlled Schmitt Trigger Relaxation Oscillator to change feedback ratio.